# Is there a way to use glade application without terminal in back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glade

I created a little application with Python3 and gtk glade, I'm using the terminal to see if I'm doing something wrong. However I want to launch the application without the terminal in the back at the end of the developement. So my question is, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file extension from `.py` to `.pyw` to make the Python script run without the terminal window. More on this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts).